# pack files relative to path with tar

Tags: linux, bash, tar

In a script I have a list of relative file paths for packing into an archive. If I use:

```
# list of some relative file paths determined at runtime
FILES="../path1/file1 ../path1/path2/file2 ../path1/file3 ... more files ..."

# pack files
tar -cavf target.tar.gz $FILES
```

the archive structure is:

```
path1/file1
path1/path2/file2
path1/file3
...
```

But I want the files packed relative to a at runtime determined path `../path1`:

```
file1
path2/file2
file3
...
```

I do not want to use the `-C` argument because then I also have to modify the paths. 
Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself. The only solution seems to edit the relative paths with `realpath`:

```
realpath --relative-to=../path1 ../path1/file1 ../path1/path2/file2 ../path1/file3 \
  | tar -acvf target.tar.gz -C ../path1  -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a detail missing from your simplified example question, but wouldn't it suffice to just move to that relative folder first?

```
cd ../path1
FILES="file1 path2/file2 file3"
tar -cavf target.tar.gz $FILES
```

Comment: @Cyrus OP said something about not wanting to use `-C`

Comment: The paths are the input and have to be modified in some way by the script to use your solution.

Comment: @R1tschY I'm truly confused by your comment. I just tested the script I posted above, and it works as is without having to be modified. I also noticed you've edited your question to include the paths inside a variable. I think the problem with that is you'll need to quote the list of paths since they're delimited by spaces.

Comment: sry, I forgot to quote the content of `FILES`. The thing is that the paths are determined at runtime. So I cannot change them manually.